# How to check if any item within a list is contained in a column's name? - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, list, substring, contains, presto

I'm wondering how I would go about checking if any item within a list is contained within the name of a column that I'm trying to select.

Suppose I have a list like: `list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cat']`. How can I check if a column's name contains any items in that list?

I was originally thinking something similar to:

```
SELECT column_name,
CASE WHEN column ('apple', 'banana', 'cat') IN column_name THEN true ELSE NULL END AS flag
FROM information_schema.columns;
```

But obviously this doesn't work. I was looking into the `SUBSTR` function as well but not sure how this would work with a list of values.

Also what I've provided is more of a minimum reproducible example. The actual list will contain around 40 elements. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT column_name,
       (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, 'apple|banana|cat') THEN true ELSE NULL
        END) AS flag
FROM information_schema.columns;
```